# How to get the color of a pixel React Native using expo

Tags: react-native, colors, expo, expo-camera

What I'm trying to do is to recognize the color of a pixel via expo-camera. I've used react-native-pixel-color but couldn't make it work. If someone has an example project I could look into I would really appreciate it.

Comment: all that libraries written as react native native modules so they don't work on expo snack :/